# Redis client for react native

Tags: android, redis, react-native

anyone know what is the list of redis client which support RN? I've trying some of nodejs redis client, but unfortunately it didn't work because it needs native nodejs library (require 'net') that react native didn't support. My use case is use pubsub. Thanks

Comment: any luck getting it to work? I have a similar use case...

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: is there any solution to this ?